# Images not rendering in AsciiDoc

Tags: macos, image, asciidoc

I've just installed asciidoc v9.0.5 using Homebrew on Mac OS 11.2, and everything seems fine, except… images just won't render. My test document is very simple…

```
:Author: That's me!
:Email: name@domain.com
:Date: 2021-02-08
:Revision: 0.0.0

== First Section

=== Subsection A

Here's an image... image:sunset.jpg
```

… and `sunset.jpg` is in the same directory as the file. But running `asciidoc {filename}` produces an HTML file with this output `<div class="paragraph"><p>Here&#8217;s an image&#8230; image:sunset.jpg</p></div>` on the line where the `image:` tag is.

I've tried using the block image macro as well, same result. Also tried various ways to manipulate the image path (e.g., prefixing with `./`, absolute paths, setting and not setting the `:imagesdir:` attribute) but nothing changes. No processing errors or log messages generated.

Any suggestions even on how I might start to untangle this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images need to be in a sub-folder called `images`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKrasnay! New to this, the docs seemed to suggest that the image root was the document root, but adding that dir works.